# JQuery Accordion issues with Safari 5.1.7

Tags: jquery, safari, accordion

I have some isues with JQuery Accordion with Safari browsers.  The content section is not getting expanded intermittently.  But the header events "activate","beforeActivate" is working normally.

I tried with various options like heightStyle etc., but it seems in Safari there are issues in ui.oldContent objects and ui.newContent objects in terms of expanding and collapsing.

Note:  In the rest of browsers like IE, Firefox, Chrome, the following script is working without any  issues and expanding/collapsing of Content section is fine.

> JQuery used:  jquery-1.10.2.min.js
>   JQuery-UI:  http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js

```
<script>
    $("#accordion").accordion( {
          collapsible : true, heightStyle: 'content'
      },
      {
          active : false
      });
      $("#accordion").accordion( {
          icons :  {
              "header" : "ui-icon-default", "activeHeader" : "ui-icon-selected"
          }
      });

      $("#accordion").accordion( {
          activate : function (event, ui) {
              ui.newHeader.children(".selected").css( {
                  "font-weight" : "bold"
              });
          }
      });
      $("#accordion").accordion( {
          beforeActivate : function (event, ui) {
              ui.oldHeader.children(".selected").css( {
                  "font-weight" : "normal"
              });
          }
      });

    </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using other jQuery version like 1.9?